# Batch script to copy file with a changing name

Tags: windows, batch-file

Our build produces an archive with the name app-component-x.x.x.x-SNAPSHOT.zip where x.x.x.x is a version number (ie: 1.6.2.8).  Directory is c:\buildresults\app

We want to write a batch script that a) copies the file to another directory with a fixed name such as build-results.zip and then b) extracts the file.

I am not sure how to do part A.   This doesn't seem to work:  `copy c:\buildresults\app\*.zip c:\xxx\build-results.zip`

Any ideas?

---

**Update**:

File is being copied BUT the size is dramatically less.  Ie: the file seems to be getting corrupted.

This seems to work but not ideal:

```
cd buildresults\app

for %%f in (*component*) do (
    echo %%~nf
    7za.exe -oC:\buildresults\app x "%%~nf.zip"
)
```

Comment: Your example works on my Windows 7 machine as long as the folder exists and I have permission to write to it. What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
xcopy /Y /Q /C /H /R c:\buildresults\app\*.zip c:\xxx\build-results.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce:

```
D:\>mkdir xxx

D:\>echo test > test-1.2.3.zip

D:\>copy test-*.zip xxx\test-current.zip
test-1.2.3.zip
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.

D:\>type xxx\test-current.zip
test

D:\>
```

Are you sure the target doesn't exist? Btw, are you sure your * matches exactly one file in every case? Because copying multiple files to one destination is a valid operation and will end up with an invalid zip file.